# IMEI SV 71 - Does it mean 71 times serviced?

Tags: android

I just checked what is SV. I came to know that it is software version number. I just found that SV is 71. So is it refurbished mobile?

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm not an expert but here is my opinion.

The IMEI SV is the software version. It increases when modifications are made on the devices software : upgrade, root, and so on. You will find more details about IMEISV [here](http://blog.cellphonedetectives.com/2015/07/todays-imeisv/) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Equipment_Identity#Structure_of_the_IMEI_and_IMEISV_(IMEI_software_version)).

In your case, the value is "huge" and it seems that this device has been frequently updated :

- many *security or regular* updates from the manufacturer
- many *manual* updates

Hope it'll help you.